# Terminals in emacs - struggling to switch over

Tags: terminal-emacs

For the past 6 months ive used kitty terminal and set it up to do everything I need.

Recently (like a month ago), I want to move all my workflows away from vim + tmux + google docs + programming etc etc.

Most of them have been migrated, and I am pleased.

However, I cannot see myself using e-shell instead of kitty. It feels... clunky?

My question here is, is there a more powerful terminal emulator within emacs that rivals the standalone emulators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs offers both *shells* and *terminals*. The shells like M-x shell and M-x e-shell work with line-by-line output. They don't work with all unix commands, but only the line-by-line ones. In return they offer more emacs integration. The terminals like M-x term and M-x vterm work with screen output. They can run programs like vim and tmux. You might want to try M-x shell instead of M-x e-shell, or try of the terminals to see if one of them matches your needs.

Comment: Note that `vterm` is a third-party package, which may or may not be compatible with your system (there are dependencies, as it integrates an external terminal emulator).  See https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm for details.